# Iterate through a dictionary array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, nested-loops

I have a String array containing a poem which has deliberate spelling mistakes. I am trying to iterate through the String array to identify the spelling mistakes by comparing the String array to a String array containing a dictionary. If possible I would like a suggestion that allows me to continue using nested for loops

```
 for (int i = 0; i < poem2.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < dictionary3.length; j++) {
            if (poem2[i].equals(dictionary3[j])) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found==false) {
            System.out.println(poem2[i]);
        }
    }
```

The output is printing out the correctly spelt words as well as the incorrectly spelt ones and I am aiming to only print out the incorrectly spelt ones. Here is how I populate the 'dictionary3' and 'poem2' arrays:

```
      char[] buffer = null;
      try {
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new 
    java.io.FileReader(poem));
        int bufferLength = (int) (new File(poem).length());
        buffer = new char[bufferLength];
        br1.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        br1.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    String text = new String(buffer);
    String[] poem2 = text.split("\\s+");

    char[] buffer2 = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(dictionary));
        int bufferLength = (int) (new File(dictionary).length());
        buffer2 = new char[bufferLength];
        br2.read(buffer2, 0, bufferLength);
        br2.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    String dictionary2 = new String(buffer);
    String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split("\n");
```

Comment: I copied your code and tried the arrays `String[] poem2 = new String[]{"test", "asdf"};` and `String[] dictionary3 = new String[]{"apple", "banana", "test"};` and correctly received only value `asdf`. Maybe there is something wrong with your dictionary?

Comment: If what you have is not working, set a break point on your "found = true" line.  It sounds as though your .equals is not working the way you expect and you're never getting a true: ie what is in poem2[i] and what is in dictionary3[j]?  are they both in fact strings?  etc etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It prints only incorrect words for me https://ideone.com/TghyDx

Comment: Can you show us where you initialize your dictionary3 and poem2 variables? I'd like to see exactly what's in them.

Comment: @Pshemo I want to print out the incorrect words

Comment: But that is what your code does contrary to what you claim in "The output is printing out the correctly spelt words as well as the incorrectly spelt one". If you are not getting expected results post proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). Also "my dictionary is a txt file" doesn't tell us much because `dictionary3` doesn't look like `File` instance, but rather as `String[]` array. You may claim that this array should be filled with content of text file, but it *isn't* a text file, nor information about its location.

Comment: @Keara I have edited my post with the code that shows where I initialise my dictionary3 and poem2 variables

Comment: @Pshemo Does my edited post provide you with a bit more clarification? Sorry it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is in line

```
String dictionary2 = new String(buffer);
```

where you ware trying to convert characters representing dictionary stored in `buffer2` but you used `buffer` (without `2` suffix). Such style of naming your variables may suggest that you either need a loop, or in this case separate method which will return for selected file array of words it holds (you can also add as method parameter delimiter on which string should be split).

So your `dictionary2` held characters from `buffer` which represented poem, not dictionary data.

Another problem is

```
String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split("\n");
```

because you are splitting here only on `\n` but some OS like Windows use `\r\n` as line separator sequence. So your dictionary array may contain words like `foo\r` instead of `foo` which will cause `poem2[i].equals(dictionary3[j]` to always fail.

To avoid this problem you can split on `\\R` (available since Java 8) or `\r?\n|\r`.

---

There are other problems in your code like closing resource within try section. If any exception will be thrown before, `close()` will never be invoked leaving unclosed resources. To solve it close resources in `finally` section (which is always executed after try - regardless if exception will be thrown or not), or better use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

---

BTW you can simplify/clarify your code responsible for reading words from files

```
List<String> poem2 = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(yourFileLocation));
while(scanner.hasNext()){//has more words
    poem2.add(scanner.next());
}
```

For dictionary instead of `List` you should use `Set/HashSet` to avoid duplicates (usually sets also have better performance when checking if they contain some elements or not). Such collections already provide methods like `contains(element)` so you wouldn't need that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran it, and I noticed two issues. Good news is, both are very quick fixes.

**#1**
When I printed out everything in `dictionary3` after it is read in, it is the exact same as everything in `poem2`. This line in your code for reading in the dictionary is the problem:

```
 String dictionary2 = new String(buffer);
```

You're using `buffer`, which was the variable you used to read in the poem. Therefore, buffer contains the poem and your poem and dictionary end up the same. I think you want to use `buffer2` instead, which is what you used to read in the dictionary:

```
 String dictionary2 = new String(buffer2);
```

When I changed that, the dictionary and poem appear to have the proper entries.

**#2**
The other problem, as Pshemo pointed out in their answer (which is completely correct, and a very good answer!) is that you are splitting on `\n` for the dictionary. The only thing I would say differently from Pshemo here is that you should probably split on `\\s+` just like you did for the poem, to stay consistent. In fact, when I debugged, I noticed that the dictionary words all have "\r" appended to the end, probably because you were splitting on `\n`. To fix this, change this line:

```
String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split("\n");
```

To this:

```
String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split("\\s+");
```

Try changing those two lines, and let us know if that resolves your issue. Best of luck!

Comment: Yay!! I'm so glad. If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it so that other users can find it easily.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your dictionary to an ArrayList and use `Contains` instead.

Something like this should work:

```
if(dictionary3.contains(poem2[i])
   found = true;
else
   found = false;
```

With this method you can also get rid of that nested loop, as the contains method handles that for you.

You can convert your Dictionary to an ArrayList with the following method:
`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))`

Comment: I can't use contains for whatever reason

Comment: Since when did they take it out?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @BrandonMiller OP is asking for arrays, what you see in `length` instead of `length()`

Comment: OKOKOKOK I see that now. Fixed my answer. @Abby if you don't feel like bashing your head against a desk trying to do this with arrays, use an ArrayList.

Comment: You don't need to use an `ArrayList`. Any type of `List` will do - including the one returned by `Arrays.asList()` so there's no need to use up unnecessary memory by copying an entire list. Also, you don't even need a `List`; just use `Arrays.contains()`.

Comment: That being said... However you choose to do it Abby, you will save yourself some headache by using the "contains" method.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException What do you mean by "Also, you don't even need a List; just use `Arrays.contains()`"? What is `Arrays.contains()`? `java.util.Arrays` doesn't have any `contains` method.

Comment: I think he meant Arrays.asList().contains()... Which is essentially storing it in memory...

Comment: @Pshemo pardon me, you are right. I must have been thinking about Apache's `ArrayUtils.contains` method and got it mixed up in my mind with Java's `Arrays` class. Rather than using a third-party library, I would just use `Arrays.asList(array).contains(element)`. In answer to Brandon's comment, it doesn't use any noticeable amount of memory as the list is backed by the original array, not a copy of it.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion that allows me to continue using the nested for loops ?

Comment: Your original code should be working, aside from the fact that your string comparison is Case-Sensitive. Try using String.equalsIgnoreCase() instead of .equals()... You probably also want to trim() your poem strings and dictionary strings before comparing. When you compare strings they have to match EXACTLY for them to be equal.